# Symfony 6 / Doctrine createQueryBuilder groupBy orderBy

Tags: symfony, doctrine

first question for me here, a problem impossible to resolve... a very simple sql request :

Here is my first table **formation_taux_horaire**, very simple (date is "start date") :

| id | formation_niveau_id | date | prix |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 10 | 2023-03-08 | 25 |
| 6 | 11 | 2023-03-08 | 30 |
| 7 | 10 | 2021-03-05 | 20 |
| 8 | 10 | 2024-03-14 | 30 |
| 9 | 10 | 2023-03-13 | 27 |

my second table **formation_niveau**, ultra simple :

| id | nom |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | Niveau III |
| 11 | Niveau IV |

I want to query the current **formation_niveau** :

```
public function enCours(): array
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('fth')
            ->andWhere('fth.date <= :ddj')
            ->setParameter('ddj', date('Y-m-d'))
            ->groupBy('fth.FormationNiveau')
            ->orderBy('fth.date', 'DESC')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult()
        ;
    }
```

The result is :

| id | nom | date | prix |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | Niveau III | 2023-03-08 | 25 € |
| 6 | Niveau IV | 2023-03-08 | 30 € |

But should be

| id | nom | date | prix |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | Niveau III | 2023-03-13 | 27 € |
| 6 | Niveau IV | 2023-03-08 | 30 € |

I don't know why ??? I'm sure the problem comes from the groupBy.

In doctrine.yaml, I've putted the option **1002: 'SET sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode, "ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY", ""))'**

I use DataTable table result.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that you **GROUP BY** your current query only grouping by the `formation_niveau` (FormationNiveau) column, without considering the latest date for each level. You can use a subquery to get the maximum date for each level and then join it back to the original tables to get the desired result.

Like this:

```
public function enCours(): array
{
    $subquery = $this->createQueryBuilder('sub_fth')
        ->select('sub_fth.formation_niveau_id, MAX(sub_fth.date) as max_date')
        ->where('sub_fth.date <= :ddj')
        ->setParameter('ddj', date('Y-m-d'))
        ->groupBy('sub_fth.formation_niveau_id')
        ->getDQL();

    return $this->createQueryBuilder('fth')
        ->select('fth, fn')
        ->innerJoin('fth.formation_niveau_id', 'fn')
        ->innerJoin(
            '(' . $subquery . ')',
            'subquery',
            'WITH',
            'fth.formation_niveau_id = subquery.formation_niveau_id AND fth.date = subquery.max_date'
        )
        ->setParameter('ddj', date('Y-m-d'))
        ->orderBy('fth.date', 'DESC')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

This is equal to the following SQL:

```
SELECT
    fth.*,
    fn.*
FROM
    formation_taux_horaire fth
INNER JOIN
    formation_niveau fn ON fth.formation_niveau_id = fn.id
INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            sub_fth.formation_niveau_id,
            MAX(sub_fth.date) as max_date
        FROM
            formation_taux_horaire sub_fth
        WHERE
            sub_fth.date <= :ddj
        GROUP BY
            sub_fth.formation_niveau_id
    ) subquery ON fth.formation_niveau_id = subquery.formation_niveau_id AND fth.date = subquery.max_date
ORDER BY
    fth.date DESC;
```

Comment: Thx for the answer, but I've an error with your solution : "Error: Class App\Entity\Formation\FormationTauxHoraire has no field or association named formation_niveau_id"